# error launching world file in gazebo

Tags: ros, gazebo-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was following [this](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=ros_roslaunch&cat=connect_ros) tutorial, but as i enter: `roslaunch my_robot_gazebo my_robot.launch`, i cant see the world in gazebo. When i enter: `env | grep GAZEBO_RESOURCE_PATH`, i cant see the gazebo in that path, when i checked my gazebo-2.2 was inside usr/share/local instead of /usr/local/share. I am using ros indigo. Befor this i have installed gazebo4 and than again uninstalled it as i knew ros indigo already provides gazebo2.2. Now i am this type of errors, what should i do? I am using ros indigo, ubuntu 14.04. I get this kind of error:

```
Error [Plugin.hh:149] Failed to load plugin libbaxter_gazebo_ros_control.so: libbaxter_gazebo_ros_control.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
[ INFO] [1471917982.987872624, 8.255000000]: GazeboRosVideo (gzserver, ns = /) has started!
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
[gazebo_gui-2] process has died [pid 13712, exit code 139, cmd /opt/ros/indigo/lib/gazebo_ros/gzclient __name:=gazebo_gui __log:=/home/dinesh/.ros/log/27d050ae-68d6-11e6-adb7-5c260a2762ef/gazebo_gui-2.log].
log file: /home/dinesh/.ros/log/27d050ae-68d6-11e6-adb7-5c260a2762ef/gazebo_gui-2*.log
Warning [Publisher.cc:134] Queue limit reached for topic /gazebo/default/pose/local/info, deleting message. This warning is printed only once.
```

What i see is when ever i run: `rosrun gazebo_ros spawn_model -file` rospack find baxter_description`/urdf/baxter.urdf -urdf -z 1 -model baxter`, the gazebo stops running.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/242180/error-launching-world-file-in-gazebo/) by [dinesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26847/dinesh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 932 on 2016-08-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [neuronet](https://answers.ros.org/users/27484/neuronet/) on 2016-08-22**:
Should mention x-posted at gazebo site: http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/14215/error-launching-world-file/

**Comment by [dinesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26847/dinesh/) on 2016-08-22**:
that is my question, i posted in both forum, to get answer quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like these packages are not publicly available?

http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/6964/baxter-gazebo-control-libbaxter_gazebo_roscontrolso/

To test gazebo alone, I would try spawning an empty world using the [gazebo_ros](http://wiki.ros.org/gazebo_ros) package.

```
roslaunch gazebo_ros empty_world.launch
```

---

Originally posted by [curranw](https://answers.ros.org/users/17736/curranw/) with karma: 211 on 2016-08-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dinesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26847/dinesh/) on 2016-08-24**:
thanks for info.